# Can I execute query via sqlalchemy without transaction

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to execute a stored procedure on Mysql database with sqlalchemy.

It runs fine from the shell but throws this error:

```
OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1568, "Transaction characteristics can't be changed while a transaction is in progress")
```

The reason as it seems is that SQLAlchemy runs query within a transaction. And the transaction within the stored procedure is conflicting with it.
Below is sqlalchemy log:

```
2019-07-24 15:20:28,888 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
2019-07-24 15:20:28,888 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2019-07-24 15:20:28,900 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2019-07-24 15:20:28,900 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2019-07-24 15:20:28,910 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine show collation where `Charset` = 'utf8mb4' and `Collation` = 'utf8mb4_bin'
2019-07-24 15:20:28,910 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2019-07-24 15:20:28,916 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2019-07-24 15:20:28,917 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2019-07-24 15:20:28,923 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2019-07-24 15:20:28,923 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2019-07-24 15:20:28,928 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test collated returns' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8mb4) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin AS anon_1
2019-07-24 15:20:28,928 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2019-07-24 15:20:28,938 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2019-07-24 15:20:28,938 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine CALL my_stored_procedure(params);
2019-07-24 15:20:28,938 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
```

What I want to know is if I can run the query from sqlalchemy without transaction. Or is there any other way to solve the problem. I tried changing the isolation level of the stored procedure but that caused table lock issues.

Answer (score 12):

SQLAlchemy always tries to execute queries inside transactions. However, one can easly end up a transaction by executing [`COMMIT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMMIT_(SQL)) statement.

First, you need a connection. Then emit a `COMMIT` using that connection, which will end up newly started transaction.

Here is a sample code that tries to create new database, which will throw an error when running inside transaction. I am using postgres, but same logic using MySQL is applicable. Trying to create new database inside transaction:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# replace URL with your MySQL instance
db_url = "postgresql://postgres:secure_pass@localhost:5432/template1"
engine = create_engine(db_url)

connection = engine.connect()

# running this query in transaction throws an error
result = connection.execute("CREATE DATABASE temp_db")
```

Will throw an error:

`ERROR: CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block`

Now, adding `COMMIT` will end up a transaction started by sqlalchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# replace url with your MySQL instance
db_url = "postgresql://postgres:secure_pass@localhost:5432/template1"
engine = create_engine(db_url)

connection = engine.connect()

# commiting will end a transaction
connection.execute("COMMIT")

# now this query runs fine
result = connection.execute("CREATE DATABASE temp_db")
```

And no errors are raised.

Comment: This is fantastic - and very clean! Note for anyone who uses the `Session` object, it would look like `session.connection().execute("COMMIT")` followed by `session.connection().execute("CREATE ...")` - even when using the underlying connection to execute the `COMMIT`, trying to do `session.execute("CREATE ...")` would still fail

Comment: Be sure to add ``session.begin()`` after making non-transactional calls with this aproach. If You will keep using session after that, I think that You may encounter some issues due to operating without transaction :) https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.begin

Comment: That errors for me - even immediately following `session.connection().execute("COMMIT")`, trying to `session.begin()` will result in `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: A transaction is already begun. Use subtransactions=True to allow subtransactions.`. I think that's what the docs linked mean when they say the `session` object always uses a transaction transparently? Maybe I'm doing something wrong, though - I'm terrible with SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Ahh, You are completly right - my bad, I was not able to try out what I've written, and posted this due to my misunderstanding. Actually, after ``conn.execute("COMMIT")`` any action on that session that affects state of transaction, will start a new transaction quietly as needed. So yes - it is likely safe to continue using that session after such commit.

Comment: Perfect! I was starting to assume it was user error on my part haha

Comment: I am curious about the low-level differences. My understanding is, for example, after we `commit` the current transaction, the command `CREATE DATABASE temp_db` should open a new transaction and run it in that transaction. It is just that the new transaction is not in SQLAlchemy control, and the database handles the transaction. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @QuanZhou see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createdatabase.html, the Notes section. It says that "CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed inside a transaction block.". I don't know exactly if this statement issues /internal/ BEGIN or not. If a transaction is internally (in PG internals) started, it cant be controlled even in direct database API access, not only by sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is not working anymore with `sqlalchemy>=2`. An alternative solution working on both `sqlalchemy>=2` and `sqlalchemy>=1.4`:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db_url = "postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/database"
engine = create_engine(db_url)

with engine.connect().execution_options(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT") as connection
    connection.execute(sqlalchemy.text("VACUUM ANALYZE table_1"))
    connection.execute(sqlalchemy.text("VACUUM ANALYZE table_2"))
```

SQLalchemy 2 will not accept raw string any more so it has to be wrapped with `sqlalchemy.text`.

A `vacuum` call has to be in its own `execute`. So it is not possible to put multiple ones in the same string, or prefixed it with another query. Else an implicit transaction will be started and it is back to the initial problem.

```py
connection.execute(sqlalchemy.text("VACUUM ANALYZE table_1; VACUUM ANALYZE table_2;"))
# InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.ActiveSqlTransaction) VACUUM cannot run inside a transaction block
```

It works because the `isolation_level` is changed to `AUTOCOMMIT`. This is done at the DBAPI so the library below `sqlalchemy`. For example `psycog2` for a `postgresql` engine.

> DBAPIs that support isolation levels also usually support the concept of true “autocommit”, which means that the DBAPI connection itself will be placed into a non-transactional autocommit mode. This usually means that the typical DBAPI behavior of emitting “BEGIN” to the database automatically no longer occurs, but it may also include other directives.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#setting-transaction-isolation-levels-including-dbapi-autocommit

As a result, you must use a DBAPI compatible with `MySQL` and `AUTOCOMMIT` mode.

You can find this information there: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mysql.html