# Remote Procedure Call from flask app on Azure SQL Database does not work

Tags: sql-server, flask, sqlalchemy, rpc

The construct is as follows: in my Azure SQL database I have a stored procedure which merges two tables. I want to call this procedure from my Flask web app. For this I create a connection using SQLAlchemy:

```py
engine = create_engine(conn_str, echo=True)
with engine.connect() as con:
    result = con.execute('{call ' + procedureName() + '}')
```

In the SQL Server Profiler Entry I see an rpc_completed
[SQL Server Profiler Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNapm.png)

However, the tables are not merged. If I run the procedure directly on the SQL server, the merge works without problems.

I also tried:
-"exec" instead of "{call ... }" in the execute statement

Comment: No much code to go on here. `autocommit=false` or `autocommit=true`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like the issue might be related to transactions. Do you use SQLAlchemy directly or throught the Flask-SQLAlchemy extension? Depending on your setup and where this code belongs in the Flask app, SQLAlchemy might start an implicit transaction every time that you have to explicitly commit. Check out the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57186725/can-i-execute-query-via-sqlalchemy-without-transaction